# Aggregate rows with specified granularity

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Input:

```
11 1
12 2
13 3
21 1
24 2
33 1
50 1
```

Let's say 1st column specify *index*. I'd like to reduce size of my data as follows:

I sum values from second column with granularity of 10 according to indices. An example:

First I consider range of 0-9 of indices. There aren't any indices from that range so sum equals 0. Next I go to the next range 10-19. There're 3 indices (11,12,13) which meet the range. I sum values from 2nd column for them, it equals 1+2+3=6. And so on...

Desirable output:

```
0 0
10 6
20 3
30 1
40 0
50 1
```

That's what I made up:

```
M=0;
awk 'FNR==NR
{
if ($1 < 10)
 { A[$1]+=$2;next }
else if($1 < $M+10)
 { 
  A[$M]+=$2;
  next
 }
else
 { $M=$M+10;
   A[$M]+=2;
   next
 }
 }END{for(i in A){print i" "A[i]}}' input_file
```

Sorry but I'm not quite good at AWK.

After some changes:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    M=10;
    if ($1 < 10){
        A[$1]+=$2;next
    } else if($1 < M+10) { 
        A[M]+=$2;   
        next
    } else { 
        M=sprintf("%d",$1/10); 
        M=M*10;  
        A[M]+=$2;
        next
    }
}END{for(i in A){print i" "A[i]}}' input
```

Comment: You'll need to try something first.  Many will see a solution but we aren't going to just give it to you.

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: And so, what does it do?  What does it not do? .....

Comment: Prints my input and then some rubbish. But only 2nd if statement is executed. Why?

Comment: So, just like other programming projects, if you aren't properly envisioning what is happening you should insert some print statements so that you can see what it's doing wrong.

Comment: @KevinDTimm is giving you excellent advice. Here is a further hint though - awk is not shell (think about that). You cannot access shell variables in awk any more than you could in C. `M=0` before your awk script is initializing a shell variable named `M` that you never use. Within your awk script you have an awk variable with the same name, `M`, but that is a totally different variable. Unlike shell, but again like C, you do not prefix an awk variable with `$` to access its value. hth.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton, I'm close to solve a problem since it works as I want but it doesn't print indices which value is 0.

Comment: Somz comments: `FNR=NR` serves no purpose so is useless. With `M=M*10`, you are going to aggregate `10,100,1000,...` instead of the expected `10,20,30,...`. Please fix the script indentation.

Comment: Whits space matters in awk. Do not put a newline between `FNR==NR` and `{`, i.e. write is as `FNR==NR {`.

Comment: @EdMorton `FNR==NR` being always true can just be removed.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
{
   ind=int($1/10)*10
   if (mxi<ind) mxi=ind
   a[ind]++
}
END {
   for (i=0; i<=mxi; i+=10) {
      s=(a[i]*(a[i]+1))/2
      print i " " s
   }
}
```